# Has anyone researched whether 7 weeks was John the baptist ministry, the 62 weeks being Jesus ministry then Jesus death in the midst of the last

Tags: jesus

It just makes sense that if in the last week of the 70 weeks we have the Messiah cut off (death on the cross) and he died in the midst of the Passover week which all so was the 50th Jubilee then the previous weeks would be weeks as well and not years.

The 62 weeks would have something to do with what Jesus did to be put on the cross. I know everyone goes with the physical rather than the spiritual to find a decree to rebuild the temple but Jesus said he would rebuild the temple in 3 days so why are people looking for a decree to build a physical temple? Jesus said John was the call to rebuild Jerusalem.

Matthew 17:11

> And Jesus answered and said unto them, Elias truly shall first come, and **restore** all things. [bold mine]

Daniel 9:25

> Know therefore and understand, that from the going forth of the commandment to **restore** and to build Jerusalem UNTO the Messiah the Prince shall be seven weeks, and threescore and two weeks: the street shall be built again, and the wall, even in troublous times. [bold mine]

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the site tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: The prophecy in Dan 9 has nothing to do with the ministry of John the Baptist and everything to do with the ministry of Jesus. Further, the time elements measure time from the "the going forth of the commend to restore and rebuild Jerusalem" (Ezra 7) which John did NOT do.

Answer (score 1):

The question is, ***"Was John the Baptist's ministry 49 days in length?"*** To ascertain that, one would need to know the day it started, and be able to prove what amounted to his ministry ending with that day known also.

The scriptures do not provide such dates. We learn from them that John the Baptist was related to Jesus and was born about six months before Jesus. He commenced his ministry "when he was about thirty years of age". It says the same about the commencement of Jesus' ministry which began after John's ministry was well under way. There is no date given for any of those events. Therefore, even if we knew the date on which John was beheaded, we still could not work out how long his ministry had lasted. Or, it might be necessary to clarify first whether the end of his ministry was the day he was imprisoned, should that be a point in question. There is no date for that either.

Consider also that immediately after John baptised Jesus, the Holy Spirit drove Jesus into the wilderness for a period of 40 days. Jesus' ministry began after that 40 day period was up. John's ministry did not end at Jesus' baptism, for it was not until later that he was imprisoned and, after an unknown length of time in prison, he was beheaded.

All of this makes it impossible to calculate the number of days John ministered.  It is back-to-front to try to make prophecies given hundreds of years before John was born fit with John's ministry. That is the worst possible way of treating prophetic scripture, I would suggest. Further, when you claim that "Jesus said John was the call to rebuild Jerusalem. Matthew 17:11" you pick on the one word 'restore' and try to align it with Daniel 9:25. However, the restoration in prophecy speaking of John was to "turn the hearts of the fathers to their children, and the hearts of the children to their fathers, or else I will come and strike  the land with a curse." Malachi 4:4  In Luke 1:17 we are told that John fulfilled that prophecy "to make ready a people prepared for the Lord."

John had nothing to do with building Jerusalem. On the contrary, Jesus foretold the destruction of Jerusalem because of their rejection (as a nation) of him as Messiah. That was a curse upon their land. Yet many individuals were prepared by John's ministry, and were restored in a spiritual sense. Daniel's prophecy cannot be made to fit in with a literal 49-day ministry of John the Baptist.